# Is Google Drive invitation only?

Tags: google-drive

When I go to drive.google.com, I see information about this service and message:

> Your Google Drive is not ready yet

with button `Notify me`.

My question is: do I need to get an invitation from another user, like it was with Google+, or is it just gradually rolling out to all users?

Comment: It's a phased rollout, although they're rolling it pretty fast. You just need to be patient.

Comment: I added the update to Google Docs (now drive) to my Android, and it asked if I wanted to enable Drive when opening the updated app.  It then took a couple of days before it was available for me to use, and I was alerted by email.

Comment: Now that Google Drive is long past the point where it's accessible to the world, it seems that this question has no further utility and should be closed (and deleted).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my case, just few hours after clicking the `Notify me` button I received e-mail, that my Google Drive is ready.

So far it looks exactly like Google Docs, only with different logo, and `docs.google.com` redirect to `drive.google.com`.

Comment: I had exactly the same. Just few hours and now I'm using Google Drive.

Answer (score 4):

Google Drive is being rolled out slowly to users who did not immediately enable it after it being launched.

This is also an option to enable it, provided to me from one of Google's support representatives:

> Another workaround is if you have an Android smartphone setup with
>   your Google account, you can visit the Marketplace and download the
>   App for Google Drive. This should force the program to your account.

You can also check [Google's official page on how to get access](https://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2456456&p=mktg_invite) to see if they've updated it.

Answer (score 1):

No. You need to go to Google Documents to enable Drive (I did it yesterday and it works), but I think it’s being rolled out gradually.

---

<sub><del>I found a [blog post](http://www.karthikk.net/2011/11/how-to-enable-google-drive-on-google-docs-right-now-tutorial/) that shows how to enable it even if you are not presented with the option upon going to Documents, but I have’t tested it so I can’t say if it works or not.</del></sub>

Comment: The blog post is from November 1st, 2011. The hack doesn't work anymore and the scripts are a little more obfuscated.

Comment: I wonder if it's down to your usage of Google Docs. I went yesterday and was presented with the "Notify Me" icon, but my son (who uses it more) got an allocation.

Comment: @ChrisF I’m not sure, because I’m not using Google Docs much.