# Download button Google Drive sync-application

Tags: google, google-drive

I have access to Google Drive. But the download button to download the sync application is not available for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/26111/is-google-drive-invitation-only

Comment: What browser? What OS? I suspect you have one that's not supported.

Comment: @ChrisF No it's not. The linked question is different. This question is about a user who already is invited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the URL that the "Download Google Drive" link sends you to:
https://tools.google.com/dlpage/drive?pli=1#eula

You should be able to download it from there.

Comment: The problem is that this links http redirects to the web-interface (drive.google.com the very same page as the link is found on bottom left corner). I think the op posted his question for this very reason.